# MacOS. How to programmatically check a new SMS message?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I want to periodically programmatically check whether a new SMS message has arrived from a specific sender. If it came, then I want to copy text the text to the clipboard.

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat with eventDescription
        set the clipboard to theMessage
    end message received
end using terms from
```

Comment: I want a burger with fries and a salad. To go. Please show us what you tried (code). Show a minimum of effort you put in this task and you'll receive help. Even if it's close to Christmas this is not about gifts and writing code for everyone.

Comment: @Pat_Morita
Thanks for the ironic answer. Sorry that I found my code useless, because I don’t think it will help. The code is attached in the question.

Comment: So what happens wit your code? Do you get the message in the clipboard? Is your question then more about the periodically checking (checked out the "on idle" handler?)